# "File not found" after first page in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, continuous-integration

In localhost my site runs correctly, after i publish it in a test server it does not work and it prints this:

[image]

My login page runs without problems...

[image]

But after i click "login", i receive the error, but the URL is correct...

[image]

my **config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://merge.***.it/merge/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'auth/login';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: use .htaccess and remove index.php

Comment: I tried with this solution https://gist.github.com/philipptempel/4226750 but not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Put blank in index_page.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

& Use .htaccess in your root folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|phpinfo\.php|Charts|assets|uploads|application|sitemap\.xml|robots\.txt|gyan\.rss)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: what did you see in the webpage?

Comment: "File not found."

Comment: Are you sure you are using right controller?
Controllers -> Auth -> Login ? what is the file structure?

Comment: structure of Auth.php controllers: https://privatebin.net/?336edf2faca9cc4a#cmGIDTLLXl5DiCm4LyW851ACDWPVm0RxW/emXH29xHE=

Comment: It's seems ok to me. don't know why its not showing.